# I want to find the ascii value of this string and the average number of character

Tags: c

I have done up to this

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{

char str[100];
int i=0;

printf("Enter any string: ");
scanf("%s",str);

printf("ASCII values of each characters of given string: ");
while(str[i])
     printf("%d ",str[i++]);


return 0;
}
```

I don't get all the ASCII values when I tried to compile it. Will you please tell me where is my mistake.

Comment: It stops where it encounters '\0', which occurs where you give space in input

Answer (score 1):

It stops where it encounters where you give space in input.

*So if you entered 
Hello World scanf will display ascii values of characters in Hello only*.

**Solution:** use `fgets`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{

char str[100];
int i=0;

printf("Enter any string: ");
fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);

printf("ASCII values of each characters of given string: ");
while(str[i])
     printf("%d ",str[i++]);


return 0;
}
```

Comment: `gets` is dangerous and deprecated

Comment: `gets` has been removed from the standard.

Answer (score 1):

First; indent your code correctly (on Linux you could use the [GNU indent](http://www.gnu.org/software/indent/) utility, or [astyle](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/)).

Compile it with all warnings and debugging info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -g`). Learn how to use the debugger (`gdb`) to run it step by step.

Then, your `scanf("%s", str);` is dangerous (should at least be `scanf("%99s", str);`, see [scanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html)) ! You could get crashes or [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) if the user enters a very long "word" of 200 characters (e.g. 200 times the digit `0`). Alos notice that `%s` reads up to a space or blank-like character. I believe it is good habit to zero a buffer before reading it. So replace your `scanf` with

```
 memset (str, 0, sizeof(str));
 fgets (str, sizeof(str), stdin);
```

At last, you are not flushing the [buffered](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_%28computer_science%29) `stdout` output (see [stdio(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdio.3.html), [setvbuf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setvbuf.3.html), [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html), etc...). Try perhaps

```
while(str[i])
  printf("%d ",str[i++]);
putchar('\n');
fflush(stdout);
```

The last call to `fflush` is useless here, but it is a good habit (or else end *every* `printf` format string with a newline `\n` since *`stdout`* is often but not always line-buffered!)

Comment: Do you want to have a +1 for suggesting GNU Indent or a -1 for suggesting GNU Indent? :)

Comment: @H2CO3: What is wrong with GNU `indent`? Also suggesting `astyle` !!

Comment: Nothing wrong, it's just that the default style it applies is nonsense, it requires quite a bunch of flags to get something readable out of it.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` stops reading if there is a space in the input string. You can either uses fgets or do the follwing:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{

   char str[100];
   int i=0;

   printf("Enter any string: ");
   str[i] = getchar();

   while(str[i]!='\n'){
        str[i+1] = getchar();
        i++;
   } 

   str[i] = '\0';
   printf("%s\n",str);

   i=0;
   printf("ASCII values of each characters of given string: ");

   while(str[i]!='\0'){
        printf("%d ",str[i++]);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:**

To find average of the string a asked by you in comments:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{

     char str[100];

   int sum=0;
   int average=0;
       int i=0;

    printf("Enter any string: ");
    str[i] = getchar();

    while(str[i]!='\n'){
        str[i+1] = getchar();
         i++;
    } 

    str[i] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n",str);

    i=0;
    printf("ASCII values of each characters of given string: ");

    while(str[i]!='\0'){
       sum = sum + str[i];
       printf("%d ",str[i++]);
    }

// To calculate average

   average = sum/(i-1);

   printf("\nAverage = %d\n",average);

       return 0;
}
```

Comment: @kounabg if it helped you .. please give an upvote and accept the answer

Comment: but, how can we find the average of the string?Can u help me?

Comment: @kounabg i have updated my solution for finding the average .. see above. Please accept solution and upvote

Comment: can u tell me why average=sum/i-1?

Comment: i want to ask that what does it mean when it say average number of character per line